# Adding features to Twilio Video SDKs

Tags: twilio, video-conferencing, twilio-video

We want to use Twilio video SDKs in our Web, Android and iOS application. Since Twilio provides everything out of the box for conferencing, but we need to add some features from our end to Twilio SDK in order to use them in our application.

Feature needed: We want to include a minimize button present in video conference room which will minimize the screen of video call and user can use the base application concurrently (similar to WhatsApp video call). Also, maximize button will be added when the minimization of call has been done so that user can switch back to video call.

Our basic requirements are:

1. Audio and Video conferencing
2. Screen sharing
3. Recording of meetings
4. Mute options control for audio/video

Participants limit:
Minimum: 3, Maximum: 50

Duration limit:
Minimum 30 minutes, Maximum 240 minutes

Requirements specific to Web Application(in React):

1. Conferencing control resides within the application. Existing Web app will be the base interface for video conferencing.
2. Anyone can mute audio/video of any participant as per his will.

Requirements specific to Mobile Application(in Flutter):

1. Flexibility to user to switch between video call and our application(identical to how WhatsApp video call works). The video call screen gets minimized and user can use the application normally and still be present in conferencing.

How could I go ahead with this? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For the Flutter solution we are building an opensource plugin hosted on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video). At the moment [screen share](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/issues/70) has not yet been added, but it will eventually. The API docs can be found [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/twilio_programmable_video/latest/twilio_programmable_video/twilio_programmable_video-library.html).

Regarding your switch like WhatApp, you need to look into the Picture-in-Picture mode (PiP). Which is also part of the development fase of this plugin. You can find the milestone [here](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/milestones/4) and the issues related to it [here](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/issues?milestone_title=Background%20modes%20and%20PiP).

You mention React for the Web. There are already plugins for React on the web. But the Web will also be implemented in the [Flutter](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/milestones/5) solution.